# Authentication with Active Directory by IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, nginx, iis

My site is hosted on IIS but behind reverse-proxy (nginx). Hence Windows Authentication is not working (nginx does not support it by default configuration). So I want IIS to use Active Directory to check user credentials. But how to do this? I suppose to use cookie, but can't find how to force IIS to find user in Active Directory database.

I would be appreciated for any help.

**UPD**:

I don't want to use Windows Authentication. I only want IIS find user in Active Directory when user send credentials by simple POST-request from the login page.

It looks like there is no integrated solution and I simply should write it by myself.

Comment: "Integrated Authentication" in IIS is not something anyone should be using anymore: it's only supported by IE11, not any other browser. Chrome _does_ support it, but only if your sysadmin opts-in to it.

Comment: "I suppose to use cookie, but can't find how to force IIS to find user in Active Directory database." - Integrated Authentication doesn't use cookies. It uses Kerberos (or NTLM, shudder) in a side-channel to perform authX and only exchanges minor details in HTTP's `Authorization` header: **Read the spec:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication

Comment: Oh, and Integrated Authentication doesn't work over the Internet because Kerberos only works in _real_ LAN environments (remember IPX? lol) because of its requirements for mutual-authentication and precise timing/network-latency, so it's a non-starter for "modern" (post-BYOD) company networks.

Comment: FWIW, ASP.NET Core **can** support Integrated Authentication with-and-without the host webserver cooperating (so it works with IIS, Kestrel, HTTP.sys, etc): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0